# Intensity images using FME software

Tags: fme-form

How to create intensity image using point cloud in FME software? I already generate using  image rasterizer transformer but the quality still need to be improved. Is there any other transformer that can give better result?
I attached sample between intensity image generated from TerraScan and FME. Intensity created from FME is not very smooth compare to intensity generate from Terrascan. I also having problem with contrast balance which I think can be solved at FME. 
[image: intensity generate from Terrascan[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDOeI.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit the question to be clearer what you need? What do you mean by "quality still needs to be improved"? Are you trying to create a raster heatmap from PointCloud data?

Comment: PointCloudFilter is a good start https://www.safe.com/transformers/point-cloud-filter/

Answer (score 2):

Did you check [Creating a Raster from a Point Cloud](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1345/creating-a-raster-from-a-point-cloud.html) tutorial from FME Knowledge center? It gives information on how to smooth your output, if this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The RasterDEMGenerator transformer might be a better fit here. It will interpolate values, whereas the NumericRasterizer is just setting a cell on/off depending on the presence of points in it.

Alternatively you could increase the spacing in the NumericRasterizer - to about 2x larger than the average spacing of points in the point cloud.

Hopefully one of those solutions will help.